# Doctrine one-to-many relation - "No identifier/primary key specified"

Tags: php, mysql, entity-framework, doctrine, many-to-one

Doctrine fails with a simple bi-directional many-to-one relationship between FoodDes (many) and FoodGroup (one). Both entities are shown here:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="FOOD_DES")
 */
class FoodDes
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->foodGroup = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="NDB_No", type="string", length=10)
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="FoodGroup", inversedBy="fdGroupCode")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="FdGrp_Cd", referencedColumnName="FdGrp_CD")
     */
    protected $foodGroup;
}
```

>

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="FD_GROUP")
 */
class FoodGroup
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Id();
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE");
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="FoodDes", mappedBy="foodGroup")
     */
    protected $fdGroupCode;
```

When I run doctrine orm:schema-tool:create, it fails with error:

> No identifier/primary key specified for Entity
>   'Acme\Entities\FoodGroup'. Every Entity must have an
>   identifier/primary key.

However, I labeled $fdGroupCode as my only identifier.

---

### Next approach

I've also tried creating a new primary key $id on the FoodGroup entity and removing the primary key label from $fdGroupCode on FoodGroup. Below is the new FoodGroup entity.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="FD_GROUP")
 */
class FoodGroup
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="FoodDes", mappedBy="foodGroup")
     */
    protected $fdGroupCode;
```

When I run doctrine orm:schema-tool:create again, it results with a new error:

> [Doctrine\ORM\ORMException]
>   Column name `FdGrp_CD` referenced for relation from
>   Acme\Entities\FoodDes towards Acme\Entities\FoodGroup does not exist.

This error doesn't make any sense. Of course it wouldn't exist. I am running it against an empty database!

These error occur running from the command line, but they also occur when querying the entities against a database. Can somebody please help me?

Comment: I've never seen declaration like this: `@ORM\Id();`. Maybe `@ORM\Id`, without brackets?

Comment: Thanks but it's the same thing. I've tried them both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd rather give you working example of OneToMany from one of my projects, so you can see the difference and format code in proper way. If it does not work, then try to get a new `Symfony` dist and start over.

```
<?php
// SomeBundle/Entity/Shop/Product.php
namespace SomeBundle\Entity\Shop;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="shop_products")
 */
class Product
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="bigint")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ProductItem", mappedBy="product")
     */
    protected $productItem;
}
```

Related entity:

```
<?php
// SomeBundle/Entity/Shop/ProductItem.php
namespace SomeBundle\Entity\Shop;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="shop_products_items")
 */
class ProductItem
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="bigint")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Product", inversedBy="productItem")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $product;
}
```

For reasons why your code does not work could be many (namespaces, folder structure, column names, etc.). This example works and tested. Give it a try : )

Comment: Wow thank you so much. I wouldn't have done it without your help.. I was just moving back to Eloquent. I would love to upvote you, but I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems that the $productItem doesn't actual represent a database column. Instead, the $id is the database column

Comment: Thats right! `$productItem` is just a link that shows Doctrine and you as well how those entities are connected together. Doctrine could be quite terrifying from time to time, but once you'll get the basics, life gets easier.